# consulta entre fechas mysql phyton

Tags: html, mysql

```
date1="2022-09-10"
date2="2022-10-10"
ejecutarListado = mysql.connection.cursor()
ejecutarListado.execute ('SELECT * FROM `registrocorte` WHERE fecha BETWEEN "2022-09-10" AND 
"2022-10-10";')
```

estoy haciendo esta consulta funciona bien cuando yo le doy las fechas pero no logro sustituirlas por las variables date1 y date 2 ya use el + de todas las dormas pero no logro que funcione

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás usando, `mysql.connector`? Si es así, está mal la definición del cursor, ver [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html):

```py
connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='el_usuario', password='el_passw',
             host='localhost', database='la_bd')

date1="2022-09-10"
date2="2022-10-10"
ejecutarListado = connection.cursor() # <-- Definiendo un cursor
$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM `registrocorte` WHERE fecha BETWEEN %s AND %s;'
ejecutarListado.execute(consulta, [date1, date2])

# Imprimiendo los resultados
for fila in ejecutarListado:
    print(fila)
```

Comment: ahora como le podria hacer para conectar ese date1 y date2 a un imput text o date en un html si me pudiera ayudar con el javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/api/listado/consulta')
@cross_origin()
def listadoConsulta():

date1="20220910"
date2="20220915"

ejecutarListado = mysql.connection.cursor()
ejecutarListado.execute ('SELECT id, folio, lote, tabla, cajas, peso_neto FROM 
`registrocorte` WHERE fecha BETWEEN ' + date1 + " AND " + date2 + ';')

datos = ejecutarListado.fetchall()
resultadoLista = []
for fila in datos:
    contenido = {'id': fila[0],
                 'folio': fila[1],
                 'lote': fila[2],
                 'tabla': fila[3],
                 'cajas': fila[4],
                 'peso_neto': fila[5]
                 }
    resultadoLista.append(contenido)
return jsonify(resultadoLista)
```

resultase que por este medio encontre que cuando la columna esta como date directo en la consulta se puede poner asi "20220921" y en mi caso fue la solucion. comparto el codigo de toda la funcion